# When should I ask for the title of a YouTube video and the title of a resume?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, web

I am designing a web site where candidates can upload videos and files. Candidate can upload videos from YouTube and they have to give the video a title and do the same thing for a file. They have to select a file to upload to the server and give the file a title.

[image]

- step 1: Candidate Record the video
- step 2: upload the video Using [youtube API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRop6.png)
- step 3: Give the title of Current video
- step 4: candidate has to select file (pdf, doc,png etc)
- Step 5 : he can give the Title of the resume
- Step 6: Click ok

This are six steps, however, I feel that this is not the right order for the form.

I feel it should be `3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6`.
I want it to be very simple for candidates to fill the form as quickly as possible. I need feedback which order is preferable.

Regarding the current order (`1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6`), I am concerned that candidates may skip giving titles.

Comment: Don't YouTube videos already have titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I got your question wrong, but I'm just wondering why you actually try to define six steps in the first place. In my opinion it would be well possible to put all input and upload fields on one page – and then let the user decide in which order he wants to fill out the fields.

Having everything in one form / one page could be particularly handy when uploading (large) video files: the user just has to fill out all fields, point the upload buttons to the files – and once you hit submit, the form would be submitted and both resume and video would be uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you're providing a video and then asking the user to upload one. Why would there be a video there already if they're just about to upload one?

You have a few options of what you could do. Like YouTube you could offer the upload option somewhere permanent no matter the video they're watching. Uploading a video has nothing to do with watching one, or any current one on screen.

[image: mock-up]

Here you narrow down the form, by providing a placeholder of how to deal with choosing the file. Have an on-click which brings up a dialog to choose the file. Upload is next to this textfield so while it's uploading (and have an AJAX spinner) to alert the user it's been acknowledged. Naturally it's the next step, because the user wants to know if it's been accepted before having to fill out all of the details. Rather than find out later and have to rewrite the information a bunch of times.

Then the user goes on to fill out the title and maybe a description. Once it's uploaded, a next button can appear at the bottom right, next to video description or a preview button.